# Cannot update Partialview after Ajax post in MVC

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax, asp.net-mvc-partialview

In my MVC application, there is a view (Details) and all the comments are listed on it via a partialview (_Comment) as shown below:

[image]

There is also an editor for adding new comments and I use Ajax call for it and then I want to display the newly added comment to the bottom of the comments by re-calling partialview with some parameters (comment body, date, user).

Note: Unnecessary codes are omitted for brevity.

**PartialView:**

```
@model Domain.Entities.Comment

@if (Model != null) { 
    @Html.Raw(string.Format("<div id='comments' class='issue-data-block'> {0} </div>",
    Model.Comment ))
}


@if (TempData["newComment "] != null)
{
    @Html.Raw(string.Format("<div id='comments' class='issue-data-block'> {0} </div>", TempData["newComment"] ))
}
```

**View:**

```
@model IssueViewModel

@foreach (var com in Model.Comments)
{
    @Html.Partial("_Comment", com)
}



<script>
$(function () {

    $('form').submit(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        kendo.ui.progress($("#kendo-loading"), true);

        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Issue/CreateComment",
                cache: false,
                //Later I will retrieve these values dynamically
                data: {
                    id: "1",
                    comment : $('#comment.text').val()
                },

                //I have no idea about the parameter values below:
                dataType: "json",
                //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                //processData: false,
                //contentType: false,
                traditional: true,

                complete: function () {
                    kendo.ui.progress($("#kendo-loading"), false);
                },
                success: function (response) {
                    if (response.success) {
                        //Here I want to recall the partialview by sending 
                        //some parameters returned from the Controller
                        // ???

                        @Html.Partial("_Comment", new ViewDataDictionary { { "Commment ", response.newComment } })

                     }
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    // $("#error_message").html(data);
                }
            }); //End of ajax call 
        });
```

**Controller:**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateComment([Bind(Exclude = null)] int id, string comment)
    {           
        Domain.Entities.Comment comment = new Domain.Entities.Comment ();
        comment .ActionBody = comment;
        comment .ActionTypeID = id;

        repository.SaveAction(action);
        return Json(new { success = true, newComment = commment });            
    }
```

Although I have tried many different approaches i.e. passing model, dictionary, string, json, etc. I encountered some problems explained below during this process and have not managed to complete it properly:

1) I think there is no need to pass whole model to the controller when creating a new comment. Instead of this, I think it is better to pass it in a dictionary. Is there any better approach you can suggest?

2) I want to append the newly added comment to the bottom of the last comment. So, I tried to recall the partial view on Ajax success, but not succeeded. Is it true approach to recall the partialview again by sending the newly added comment to it? If so how can I do this?

Comment: Why return the comment from the controller? You have created it in the view so you already know the values. Just dynamically add new html in the `success` callback

Comment: @StephenMuecke Hi Stephen, it is very nice to hear from you again :) I know it is bad idea to return the comment to the view as it is already comes from view, but when I use data parameter in Ajax success, encounter an error "The name data does not exist current context". So, how can I solve this? Could you examine the question an clarify me regarding to the proper solution by posting the corrected code pls?

Comment: Have a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9madrh7g/2/) I created for a similar question and let me know if its suitable (its a slightly different UI since it uses a pop-up for entering new data, but it shows how when you close the popup, the new item is added to the DOM

Comment: Not sure that this is your problem but you write  data: {id: "1",comment: $('#comment.text')}. if you want comment to be a string you need to call $('#comment.text').val() (if you are targeting the textarea) or $('#comment.text').text() if you are targeting a div/span

Comment: @tabz100 Actually it is not important, the code was correct in my project and I also updated it on the question as well thanks. Any idea regarding to the question?

Comment: @StephenMuecke Many thanks for your help. Actually the idea is almost the same in your example, but if you would not mind, could it be possible to correct the mistakes in my code (Ajax especially) and clarify me regarding to the question I posted?

Comment: @Christof, I assume that your last edit should have in fact been `comment : $('#comment').val()` (not `comment.text`). Give me a hour and I'll post an answer - you have a few other issues with your code such as the partial having `<div id="comments" ...>` which will create duplicate `id` attributes (invalid html)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Ok, I am looking for your valuable answer, thanks. On the other hand, it might also be good idea to append the newly created div to the bottom of the comments instead of recalling the partialview on ajax success. But do not have any idea how to do this?

Comment: I'll address that in my answer, but can you confirm that you only want to display existing (and newly added) comments - i.e you don't need to edit them (only create them).

Comment: Yes, I just want to append the newly added comment to just below the last  current comment. Editing is also another issue and maybe I look at later. I think of a temporary editing of the last added comment as in the stackoverflow. If it is easy you can post such a kind of property also, but if complex forget it :)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Sorry for late answer, I just completed the test and it is really wonderful. Many thanks again for your kind helps. Voted+++

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the working and updated code of @Stephen Muecke's wonderful solution below. ı hope this will also useful for those who look for such a kind of solution or method. Many thanks again to @Stephen Muecke again for his help and clever solutions :) Please note that all the unnecessary code has been removed for brevity.

**View:**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("CreateComment", "Issue", FormMethod.Post,
    new { id = "frmDetails" })) 
{
    <div id="comments">
    @foreach (var action in Model.Actions)
    {
        //List each comment in Actions with the given format :                                
        @Html.Raw(string.Format("<div class='issue-data-block'><a href=''><strong>{0}</strong></a>| {1} <br /><p> {2} </p></div>",
            action.AuthorID, action.Created.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy - HH:mm"), action.ActionBody))                               
    }
    </div>

    @*New comments first rendered on here before appending to the "comments" div above*@
    <div id="template" class="hidden">
        <div class="issue-data-block"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="pull-left">
        @(Html.Kendo().Button().Name("btnComment"))
    </div>

    <div id="addComment" style="display: none; ">
        @(Html.Kendo().EditorFor(m => m.Action.ActionBody)
            .Name("CommentBody")
        )
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Action.ActionBody)
        <br />

        <div class="pull-left">
            @(Html.Kendo().Button().Name("btnCancelComment"))

            @(Html.Kendo().Button().Name("btnAddComment"))
        </div>
    </div>
}

<script>

var decodeEntities = (function () {
    // this prevents any overhead from creating the object each time
    var element = document.createElement('div');

    function decodeHTMLEntities(str) {
        if (str && typeof str === 'string') {
            // strip script/html tags
            str = str.replace(/<script[^>]*>([\S\s]*?)<\/script>/gmi, '');
            str = str.replace(/<\/?\w(?:[^"'>]|"[^"]*"|'[^']*')*>/gmi, '');
            element.innerHTML = str;
            str = element.textContent;
            element.textContent = '';
        }
        return str;
    }
    return decodeHTMLEntities;
})(); 

//returns raw Html from given string
function RawHtml(str) {
    return $('<div/>').html(str).text();
}



$('#btnAddComment').click(function () {
    var url = '@Url.Action("AddComment")';
    var issueId = '@Model.ID'; 
    var commentBody = $("#CommentBody").val();
    var token = $('[name=__RequestVerificationToken]').val();
    var existingComments = $('#comments');

    var comment = decodeEntities(commentBody);

    $.post(url, { comment: comment, IssueID: issueId, __RequestVerificationToken: token }, function (data) {
        if (!data.success) {
            return;
        }
        else if (data.success) {
            var newComment = $('#template').children('div').clone();
            newComment.text(comment);
            var comm = "<div class='issue-data-block'><a href=''><strong>" + data.userId + "</strong></a>| " + data.created + " <br /><p> " + RawHtml(newComment) + " </p></div>";
            existingComments.append(comm);

            //Clear Kendo Editor content
            var editor = $("#CommentBody").data("kendoEditor");
            editor.value('');
        }
    }).error(function (data) {
            // oops something went wrong
    });
});

</script>
```

**Controller:**

```
[HttpPost, ValidateInput(false)]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public JsonResult AddComment(string comment, int IssueID)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(comment))
    {
        Action action = new Action();
        action.ActionBody = comment;
        action.IssueID = IssueID;

        repository.SaveAction(action);
        return Json(new { success = true, userId = GetUser.Id, created = action.Created.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy - HH:mm") });
    }
    return Json(new { success = false, message = "Error..." }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```